# Can I change the access modifier of generated safe nav args?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-safe-args

I am using safe nav args in my application. The point is that I have an internal class that should be passed from fragment A to fragment B. Both fragments are internal as well. The generated safe args class is public so I get that error.

```
'public' function exposes its 'internal' parameter
```

which makes sense.

My question is can I change the access modifier of the generated nav args class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem got resolved in version

```
classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.4.0"
```

and by applying the plugin

```
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"
```

instead of

```
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
```

Comment: by using suggested, it started to generate on java

Comment: @ДмитроЯковлєв 
As far as I know, this is not doable since the access level of the types passed through the Kotlin safe nav args plugin should be at least public.
You can consider using bundle instead of safe args if you need a totally Kotlin solution.